# BST:-Given the inorder successor of each node,find the parent of each node in O(h)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

The title sums it up,
I have an array which contains the node,its inorder sucessor I need to implement a subroutine to find parent of any given node in O(h)

The left and right pointers are not given

Comment: Are you sure that you formulated the question correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure because if the left and right of each node is given then the question can be done without using the successors but i am not sure whether a solution exists.

Comment: I believe you can't disambiguate the tree with the information you've provided. Better update your question with an example

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, in-ordered successor in a BST simply means the next higher element. Now provided this information, it is possible to create more than one BST.
say for example [{1,4},{2,1},{3,2},{5,3}] here {a,b} means a is the node and b is the in-ordered successor. so one possible implementation of tree is 4 IPO(read is parent of) 1 and NULL, 1 IPO 2 and NULL, 2 IPO 3 and NULL and finally 3 IPO 5 and NULL. This information can be found in O(n) complexity as u need to traverse the array only once.